# App not launching as default in restricted user account

Tags: android, android-intent, default, android-launcher

I have an android app running on a tablet that has just been updated to 5.0.2 (Thanks to the generosity of google). Before it was updated (4.4) it was having the same issue. So it's not specific to lollipop.

I run the app on the admin user account and on a restricted user account, with permissions only to run this app.

I have intent filters in `MainActivity`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

When I run the app on the admin user, it launches with the app. When I try to navigate from the app, it gives me the option to open the home page as the app or as the tablet homepage, with options once, or always. This works.

However when I run the app in the restricted user account, it never launches with the app and there's no option to (obviously, as I've restricted it) to set it as the default.

I have tried setting the app to launch always in the admin account, makes no difference. Is there a way to over come this? I would prefer a solution that is applicable to 4.3 or 4.4 as opposed to just lollipop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

I went to the restricted user account and cleared the default settings for the home page. The option was then presented to use the app as default, always or once, like for the admin user.

I then fixed the `onBackPressed` event.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}
```

So the user can only navigate between the app and the settings, unless they want to clear the default settings.

This works well to create a device that will only work for specified apps, for device controls.. except I need to circumvent the user from uninstalling the app. Even though the user is able to change the default, the restricted user settings prevent the user from using any other features of the device.

So now to figure out how to prevent the user from uninstalling the app and the default..